# Azure App Service Auto-Scaling - handle new outbound IP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

I am wondering how people handle the situation where an Azure Web App is configured with Auto-Scale that relies on services where IP whitelists have been configured.

For example, lets say I have a Website (Web A) and another App Service (App B) that is providing an API. I would like to set the firewall rules on App B such that Web A only has access to it using IP Whitelisting.

In this scenario, if Web A satisfies the Auto-Scale rules, there is a potential that the newly scaled instance will have a different outbound IP (from my understanding of the documentation there is a chance of receiving a different outbound IP at least).
How would I ensure that App B includes this new outbound IP?

In this scenario we already have username/password authentication, but as an added layer of security I would also like to configure IP whitelisting.

Comment: @AnasBinNazeer whenever you can, do more within a suggested edit than just removing thanks. Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19348121) should be flagged as Too Broad, rather than put into another review queue.

Comment: I've just put a flavour of an answer to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909095/861315

Answer (score 0):

> If Web A satisfies the Auto-Scale rules there is a potential that the newly scaled instance will have a different outbound IP [...]

No. All scale out operations take place within the scale unit (stamp), meaning same outbound IP addresses for all your instances.

Secure your service to service calls with [OAuth 2.0 client credential grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api) (access tokens), or X509 client certificates. The IP address way isn't a very cloud way of restricting access, you should look at IP addresses as ephemeral by nature in the cloud and deal with access at a higher layer in the OSI model.

Answer (score 0):

just had the same question and found this lately in the docs: [image]

Link to the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips)

So in a nutshell: If you scale out it should work out, if you scale up between app service plan tiers the outbound ip adresses will change

Answer (score -1):

What you describe here is exactly how this service works.

There is no way to tell exactly from which IP a request will be coming to you API. The web app might, without any further notice, transfer the app to a different instance, hence the request will be coming from there.

However, there are also other ways to secure your API.

I recommend you have a look at adding AzureAD authorization in-front of your API and require all requests to be authorized before they can interact with your API.

See e.g. how to

- [Call a web API with the signed-in user's permissions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect), or
- [Call a web API with the application's permissions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity)